# React set state based on prime number detection

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to change state in a React component depending on the number output by clicking a button.  The button increments a counter in state. If the number is prime, it should change the isPrime state to true; if not isPrime should be false.

```
  class Counter extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          count:0,
          isPrime: false
        };
      }

checkPrime = (num) => {
    if (num === 1) return false;
    if (num === 2) return true;
    for(var i = 2; i < num; i++) {
        if(num % i === 0) {
            return false; // it isn't prime
        }
    }
    return true; //it is prime
  }

incrementItem = () => {
    this.setState((prevState, { count }) => ({
    count: prevState.count + 1
  }));
    if (this.checkPrime(this.state.count)) {
        this.setState({ isPrime: true });
    }
    else {
        this.setState({ isPrime: false });
    }
}


render() {
    return (
      <div id="mainDiv" className={this.state.isPrime ? 'bgPrime' : ''}>
        <button onClick={this.incrementItem}>Click me</button>
        {<h2>{ this.state.count }</h2> }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Counter;
```

In the incrementItem function, I couldn't get the following syntax to work as suggested [here](https://wsvincent.com/react-counter/):

```
    this.setState((prevState, { isPrime }) => {
            isPrime: true
     });
// ('Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions')
```

Comment: Wrap `{ isPrime: true }` in parens: `this.setState((prevState, { isPrime }) => ({ isPrime: true});`.

Comment: I don't know what's going on with that suggestion, but if you pass a function to setState it receives state and props as arguments.  The first argument is always "prevState".  And as Tex suggests, the syntax is incorrect because the `{}` are being interpreted as a function block.  You'd have to wrap them in params.

Comment: Thanks but when I do that, it complains about the semicolon (' Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ",") .

Comment: Although after looking at the code again, I'm not sure why you'd want to do that, and the code example looks iffy in a couple of places.`this.setState((prevState, { count })` could just be `this.setState((prevState)`, and `setState` is [asynchronous](https://medium.com/@wereHamster/beware-react-setstate-is-asynchronous-ce87ef1a9cf3), meaning `this.state.count` may not include the updated `count` immediately after you've set it.

Comment: I thought the point of the function to set state was that it would make it happen immediately

Comment: Nope, `setState` is asynchronous - also see the answer from @estus .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this `incrementItem` method:

```
incrementItem = () => {
  this.setState((prevState) => {
    const count = prevState.count + 1
    return { count, isPrime: this.checkPrime(count) }
  })
}
```

It should work because `count` is updated immediately and synchronously, then used by `this.checkPrime`, rather than trying to access `this.state.count` before it's been updated by `setState`.

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion was implemented incorrectly. What [this article](https://wsvincent.com/react-counter/) suggested is to use [updater function](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate), which is *first* `setState` argument. Updater function accepts previous state and current props as parameter and returns new state:

```
this.setState((prevState, props) => ({ isPrime: true }));
```

Since neither state not props aren't used in new state, there's no need for updater function. If the update was unconditional, it would be just:

```
this.setState({ isPrime: true });
```

But the purpose of updater function is to prevent race conditions because state updates are asynchronous. This piece will cause race conditions because `state.count` may be accessed before it was updated:

```
this.setState((prevState, { count }) => ({
  count: prevState.count + 1
}));
if (this.checkPrime(this.state.count)) {
...
```

Instead, both state updates should be done with updater functions to keep the order in which they are executed:

```
incrementItem = () => {
  this.setState((prevState) => ({
    count: prevState.count + 1
  }));

  this.setState((prevState) => ({
    isPrime: this.checkPrime(prevState.count)
  }));
}
```

Comment: While this is fine,  you might as well wrap everything in a single updater function (see my answer).

Comment: That's true. They can be written this way or another, depending on dev's preferences and a possibility that there may be a need to decouple these updates later.

Comment: Either answer could be marked as correct.  Thank you!!